# vertical scroll call not working in Firefox but works in chrome?

Tags: angularjs

Inner vertical scroll is not working in Firefox but works in chrome browser when it is operated with arrow keys in keyboard.

Comment: Can you provide some source code? seems related to a focus problem of your views..

Comment: when there are two scroll in the page..the inner scroll doesn't work. This happens in Firefox browser alone.